# How to separate each string in a table view array into its own cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift-array

I am building an app using swift and have created an array with over 700 rows displayed in the table view. The issue is that I need each row to occupy its own individual cell, but all 700 text strings are grouped to one table view cell. How do I go about separating each string to its own cell without manual creating and labeling 700+ new tableviewcells?

EDIT: Thanks for the help! It seems I really didn't understand how table views worked. I've now made custom tableviewcells and should get the result I'm looking for this way.

Comment: You apparently don't understand how table views work. I suggest you read the "Table View Programming Guide for iOS".

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have your array `let myData = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]`

Make sure your `UIViewController` inherits `UITableViewDataSource`

Override the following methods and modify accordingly

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myData.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Should ideally get UITableViewCell using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = myData[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: That is actually what I already have. What I mean is that they are not separated into separate editable cells. If I change the style from plain to grouped, it shows that they are all grouped into one tableviewcell. I am trying to however, say if I set it to grouped, show that each string is in its own tableviewcell group

Comment: @user4938361 post some pictures, and read the documentation, it seems you don't understand how sections work in a table view.